# how to get selected (integer) id of radio button in android

Tags: android, radio-button

However I'm getting unique id but don't know how to get id like 1,2...I have posted my code below...

```
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId){      
    Global.id=(int)buttongroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();               
    System.out.println("selected Global Id:"+Global.id);                
    System.out.println("selected id"+Global.id);                
    btn=(RadioButton)findViewById(Global.id);               
    btn.setChecked(true);               
    Global.buttonname=(String)btn.getText();                
    System.out.println("selected radio button"+Global.buttonname);              
}
```

02-25 14:59:38.042: I/System.out(8717): selected Global Id:2131427346

02-25 14:59:38.042: I/System.out(8717): selected id2131427346

Comment: what are 1,2 for you?

Comment: id like 1,2.. -- Can you explain this exactly what you want since you are already getting the button ID?

Comment: I'm getting unique id like 21314757...but I need id like 1,2,3...based on the id value,I have to perform operation in switch case....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can switch on the id:

```
switch(checkedId) {
  case R.id.name_of_fist_radiobutton:
   /// my operation form 1;
   break;
   case R.id.name_of_second_radiobutton:
   /// my operation form 2;
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get value:

```
String radiovalue=  (RadioButton)this.findViewById(group.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
```